# Heroku pg:push psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I know similar questions have been asked but none of the solutions have worked. I am trying to push my local db to my Heroku db, and I keep getting psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "windows username".

I am on windows, so I tried SET PGUSER=postgres SET PGPASSWORD=password

Then ran  heroku pg:push localdb DATABASE_URL --app herokuapp

But am still getting this stupid password error. The thing is it still looks like it is using my windows user name and not postgres username.... how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Heroku support I was finally able to get this to work. So for Windows users, these are the steps:

First you want to dump your local database out to a dump file:

```
pg_dump --verbose -F c -Z 0 -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 yourdbname > local.dump
```

Then you want to grab the connection string from your heroku application config vars:

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
```

Then you want to pick out the username / hostname / databasename parts from the connection string, ie: postgres:// username : password @ hostname : port / databasename
***One warning, running this against a production database with real data is something you want to avoid so be careful with pg_restore. When running this manually you run the risk of mangling your data without the CLI check, so you may want to manually verify that the target database is empty first.***

```
pg_restore --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -U username -h hostname -p 5432 -d databasename < local.dump
```

Then when prompted for a password, just paste in the password from the connection string

Comment: If it gives the error: 
 pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header

then check that in the pg_restore you have the -F c part as in previous step with pg_dump

Comment: I run into `<` operator is reserved for future use. Have tried using the `|` instead of the `<` and also `-f` .None of them worked. Any workaround suggested ? Am using Powershell on VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `SET PGUSER=postgres`. This is important as otherwise heroku will use a different user and your password will not work.
2. Run `heroku pg:push localdb DATABASE_URL --app herokuapp`
3. Enter your password for `postgres` when it prompts.

Comment: how should I go about the first command ?, is that an environment variable

Comment: Yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the exact same problem and was successful in resolving this.
Rather than use the single line 'heroku pg:push' command with / without username/password, I relied instead on 2-steps:
Step-1: pg_dump
Step-2: pg_restore

This as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051445/na-peters above
as well as briefly hinted by Heroku at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql

Key thing is the password to enter is NOT the password you'd use when accessing your local Postgresql database. Instead, the password is a 64-character string you will obtain from:
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a

To extract it follow instructions by NA Peters above (it is the y string between : and @ in the postgres://xxxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@hhhhhh:5432/dddddd
Expect it to work

Answer (score 0):

For you Windows PowerShell folks out there struggling with the restore, try:

```
Get-Content -raw local.dump | pg_restore -F c --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -U <username> -h <hostname> -p 5432 -d <databasename>
```

Then paste the password in when prompted.