# postgres showing authentication failed when given correct password

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, deployment

Ok, so I have installed Postgres Database with zeal, and during installation, i was prompted for a password which i entered, now when I try to start *psql shell* it gives me below mentioned error, but when i start *Pgadmin* it logs me in fine, No Clue here!

**Authentication error in CMD**

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "atifs"
```

Now i am trying to push my local *Db to Heroku* during this process i am asked for a password, and this error again, which password is it asking,  because I clearly remember the password and i have given only one that too at the installation, i am close to being frustrated, need help,
Thanks in advance

**Heroku error**

```
heroku pg:push postgres DATABASE_URL -a immense-anchorage-56196  »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.0. heroku-cli: Pushing postgres ---> postgresql-opaque-17681 Password: pg_dump: error: connection to database "postgres" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "atifs" pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file  !    pg_dump errored with 1
```

**update**

even after `set PGUSER=postgres` it is still giving me the same error

Comment: What is `zeal`? Postgres version? OS and version? Have you tried logging in as `postgres` user with the password you created e.g. `psql -d postgres -U postgres`? Add answers as updates to your question.

Comment: no , lol i mean to say with enthusiasm, tried to add little humour to it , Yes `postgres` user , i simply enter `psql` and then it asks for password `OS win 10 `

Comment: Add the complete command line you use to connect with `psql` to the question. If you followed the install from here [EDB Install](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/supported-open-source/postgresql/installer/02_installing_postgresql_with_the_graphical_installation_wizard/01_invoking_the_graphical_installer/) the password you created should work for user `postgres`. Is there more then one instance of Postgres installed on the machine?

Comment: i created a password for `superuser` , no more than one, I simply type `psql` in cmd, and it asks me for a password, but now i believe the password which it asks me for is not the superuser password, which is it then?                                   
 `C:\Users\atifs>psql`
`Password for user atifs:`

Comment: I repeat the password you created is for user `postgres`. In the cmd enter `psql -d postgres,  -U postgres` and when it prompts for the password use the password you created when you did the install. Please actually read the comments in full.

Comment: i completely understand that now , but I want my `postgres` username to take over default username, how do i attain that, tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494463/heroku-pgpush-psql-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user

Comment: Not clear to me whether you are talking about the local command line or the Heroku script? For local do `psql -d postgres,  -U postgres` and for Heroku include the username in the `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: in local cmd issue is fixed but in Heroku, its still the same, issue still persists, i have updated my question

Comment: Then include the `postgres` user in the `DATABASE_URL` or use the `env` variables shown here [Env vars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).